# PHP Try Catch Finally Issue

Tags: php, debugging, try-catch

I got stuck working in an error logging piece that I'm working on, and ultimately it devolved into the following:

```
$errorMsg = 'No Errors Detected';
try{
    nonexistentfunction();     //Basically something here will not work
}catch(Exception $e){
    $errorMsg = 'Oh well, something went wrong';
}finally{
    $this->logger->log($errorMsg);
}
```

However, every time the logger logs the message 'No Errors Detected' while it should be logging 'Oh well, something went wrong' because I'm throwing an exception (method not found in this example, but any exception can occur).

How do I get the code in the catch() block to execute? It doesn't seem to execute at all!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Are you using Namespaces? Try `} catch(\Exception $e) {`

Comment: @RahulBhatnagar try to use this `throw new \Exception("Custom exception!")` instead of `nonexistentfunction()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call an undefined function in PHP, it'll throw a fatal error, not an exception.

You'd therefore need to catch an object of type `Error`. Alternatively, you can catch `Throwable` objects, from with both `Error` and `Exception` classes extend.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php

```
<?php

$errorMsg = 'No Errors Detected';

try {
    nonexistentfunction();
}
catch (Throwable $e) {
    $errorMsg = 'Oh well, something went wrong';
}
finally{
    $this->logger->log($errorMsg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although I was not actually calling a non-existent function, however this answer gives me a more complete understanding of why catch was not working, hence marked as correct.